# extraer un numero en una cadena python

Tags: python, string

En un codigo de Python tengo lo siguiente:
tiempo =  "6.3789567433 Minutos "

me gustaria obtener solamente 6.3789567433.  Como podria hacerlo?

Comment: Bienvenido, recuerda agregar lo que trataste o investigaste por favor , revisa [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tu variable tiempo sigue siempre la misma estructura del ejemplo (es decir, valor+espacio+Minutos) puedes usar `split`

```
tiempo = "6.3789567433 Minutos"
mivar = float(tiempo.split(' ')[0])
```

Esto almacenará en la variable `mivar` la parte numérica como número, para poder hacer operaciones con él. He usado `float` porque entiendo que son decimales.

Answer (score 0):

Una forma más general de extraer un valor de una cadena es usar una expresión regular.

En este caso, queremos identificar un valor de punto flotante, que es algo que tiene un punto decimal y uno o más dígitos a la izquierda y/o derecha.

Necesitamos dos expresiones regulares: `\d*\.\d+`, que reconoce valores que tengan parte decimal; y `\d+.\d*`, que reconoce valores con parte entera. Para reconocer cualquiera de ambos casos (o combinación) , usamos el operador `|` (operador OR).

```
\d*\.\d+|\d+.\d*
```

Ponemos la expresión entre paréntesis para "capturar" la cadena reconocida por la expresión regular y usamos `findall(patron, cadena)` para obtener una lista con todas los valores encontrados en la cadena:

```
re.findall("(\d*\.\d+|\d+.\d*)", "1.23 seconds .34 minutos 2. hola . "))
```

Esto devuelve una lista de cadenas:

```
['1.23', '.34', '2.']
```

que sólo resta convertir a valores numéricos usando `float`.

El proceso completo es:

```
lista = [float(x) for x in re.findall("(\d*\.\d+|\d+.\d*)", "1.23 seconds .34 minutos 2. hola . ")]
print(lista)
```

produce:

```
[1.23, 0.34, 2.0]
```